# Python - Type Hinting specific sized Vectors

Tags: python, initialization, user-interaction

Considering a class method that takes a "vector" (Tuple or List of either `int` or `float`) of defined values such as the following:

```py
import sys
from numpy import isnan, array, float64

class Shape:
"""
This is the Shape class. 
Create 3D shapes described by a length 3 vector dimension input.
Example: 
>>x=y=z=2.5
>>Shape([x,y,z])
"""
   def __init__(self,dimension): 
        self.dimension = array(dimension, dtype=float64, copy=False)
        if any(isnan(self.dimension))  or  len(self.dimension)!= 3:
            sys.exit('Bad dimension input')
        ### more dimension sensitive code
```

---

How could one Type Hint this so it is communicated that I can have valid inputs such as the following?

```
Shape([1,2,3])
Shape([1.0,2.0,3.0])
Shape((1.0,2.0,3.0))
```

---

For now, I have the following hack which I think looks *jarring* but people like it:

```
import ...
x=y=z=None ## Placeholder type hinting(????)

class Shape:
"""
Lorem Ipsum
"""
   def __init__(self,dimension=[x,y,z]): 
        self.dimension = array(dimension, dtype=float64, copy=False)
        if any(isnan(self.dimension))  or  len(self.dimension)!= 3:
            sys.exit('Bad dimension input')
        ### more dimension sensitive code
```

Of course this suggests nothing about the type of the vector data but at least shows it is a 3 sized vector with known symbols (x,y,z) to my users.

Comment: I do not think you can hint at the length of a list or tuple since those types do not specify a particular length.

Comment: If that's the case, would the provided hack be a sensible solution? It still gives me the wrong type (`List[None]`) around the corner but gets some of the job "done"; I've been wondering if I've been missing something for situations like these.

Comment: Something like [`Tuple[float, float, float]`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Tuple)?

Comment: So I was very wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python does have optional typing, which you can use like this:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Tuple
from numpy import array, float64, isnan
import sys

T = TypeVar('T', int, float)

class Shape:
   def __init__(self, dimension: Tuple[T, T, T]=[None,None,None]) -> None: 
        self.dimension = array(dimension, dtype=float64, copy=False)
        if any(isnan(self.dimension))  or  len(self.dimension)!= 3:
            sys.exit('Bad dimension input')
```

This doesn't really do too much, but will show up if for example someone calls `help(Shape)` (give it a try).  There are also linters which will use this typing and pull someone up with a warning if they do something wrong, but the program will run anyway.

Comment: This is fantastic, TypeVar is easier to work with than I thought! I believe this can be used to specify Tuples within Tuples as well which could come in handy.